# How call second oracle overloaded stored procedure with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, stored-procedures

I have overloaded stored procedure in Oracle:

```
#v1
www.get_playerhistory
  date_from: STRING
  date_to: STRING
  player: INTEGER
  result: SYS_REFCURSOR

#v2
www.get_playerhistory
  date_from: DATE
  date_to: DATE
  player: INTEGER
  area_code: INTEGER
  result: SYS_REFCURSOR
```

I don't have access to the function. But I need call second version of the function.

```vb
Dim con As Object: Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
con.Open getConnectionString()

Dim cmd As Object: Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "www.get_playerhistory"
cmd.CommandType = 4

Dim dateFrom As Object: Set dateFrom = cmd.CreateParameter("date_from", 133)
cmd.Parameters.Append dateFrom
dateFrom.Value = DateAdd("d", -1, today)

Dim dateTo As Object: Set dateTo = cmd.CreateParameter("date_to", 133)
cmd.Parameters.Append dateTo
dateTo.Value = today

Dim player As Object: Set player = cmd.CreateParameter("player", 3)
cmd.Parameters.Append player
player.Value = playerId

Dim areaCode As Object: Set areaCode = cmd.CreateParameter("area_code", 3)
cmd.Parameters.Append areaCode
areaCode.Value = areaId

Dim rst As Object: Set rst = cmd.Execute
```

I often call functions like this:

```vb
Set rst = con.Execute("{ call www.get_playerhistory(to_date('" & DateAdd("d", -1, today) & "', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), to_date('" & today & "', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), " & playerId & ", " & areaId & ")}");
```

`Set rst = cmd.Execute` returns an error: `[Oracle][ODBC] Wrong number of parameters.`

Comment: Sounds like the user you are connected as might just not have execute privs on the second version of the procedure? (Or is `www` is a package rather than a schema, the second version is in the body but not the spec; or the argument names aren't quite what you expect...)

Comment: if I run this procedure from oracle sql developer, it works correctly.

Comment: As the same user you connect with from VBA? Or as the procedure owner?

Comment: Maybe try `cmd.CommandType = 1` with `cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN www.get_playerhistory(?,?,?,?); END;"` or `cmd.CommandText = "{CALL www.get_playerhistory(?,?,?,?)}"`

Comment: @AlexPoole as the same user.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I used this way, the result is the same.